# Prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(a+e^x)(1-e^{-x})}dx=\frac{\pi^2+\big(\ln(a)\big)^2}{2(a+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I was having trouble proving this integral result:

> Prove
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(a+e^x)(1-e^{-x})}dx=\frac{\pi^2+\big(\ln(a)\big)^2}{2(a+1)}$$

**My Attempt**

let $u=e^x, \; du=e^x dx$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(a+e^x)(1-e^{-x})}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^x}{(a+e^x)(e^x-1)}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(u)}{(a+u)(u-1)}du=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(u)}{(a+u)(u+e^{\pi i})}du$$

What do I need to substitute after this? How do I solve this integral? Thank you for your time